# Problems accessing text file to create a password guessing game

Tags: python, string, passwords

I'm using python and a text file with the top 12,000 most common passwords. It's a game for educational purposes where the program needs to be able to access the text file to then check if it's the correct password.

It might be a problem with accessing the top 12,000 passwords file, but heres the code:

```
import string
import os

password = "martin"
line = 1

file = open(r"bots\passwords.txt")

while line > 12000:
    pw = file.readline(line)
    if pw == password:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the program as close to the original as possible, here's a fixed version of your program. Changes are noted in comments

```py
import os

password = "martin"
line = 1

file = open(r"bots\passwords.txt")

while line < 12000: # run while line is less than 12000, not greater
    pw = file.readline(line).strip() # file.readline(...) will return linebreaks that you don't want to compare against
    if pw == password:
        print("Found on line", line)
        break
    line+=1 # increment the line counter
```

This can also be cleaned up and made simpler by using python's `file.readlines()` function

```py
import os

password = "martin"

with open(r"bots\passwords.txt") as file: # automatically close file when done reading
    lines = file.readlines()

for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    pw = line.strip()
    if pw == password:
        print("Found on line", i)
        break
```

Comment: Yes, use the original path from your code

Comment: thanks man, had to replace the path but it works, much love

Answer (score 0):

Try to use readlines with for loop, so it will work without problems

```py
password = "martin" #search martin in the text file

with open('passwords.txt') as file: #open file in read mode
    for pw in file.readlines(): #make a loop
        if password in pw: #check if martin in the file if found print the line and break the loop at first result, you can remove break so it will print every word contains martin
            print(pw.strip())
            break
```

The output will be something like

```
hello martin the password is wrong!
```

if you want the exactly match use

```py
password = "martin"
current_line = 0

with open('passwords.txt') as file:
    for pw in file.readlines():
        if password == pw.strip():
            print(f"Found '{pw.strip()}' at line '{current_line}'")
            break
        current_line += 1
```

And the output will be

```
Found 'martin' at line '12002'
```

To make you sure, this will never be executed:

```py
line = 1
while line > 12000: #line which equals 1 is smaller than 12000 so it will return False
```

btw you should to close the opened file, hope it was helpful :)

Answer (score -2):

The problem here is probably **accessing the file**. Saying that it has the permissions to access the file, make sure that you direct the code into finding the file. Here, you probably have the code and the password file in the same folder(bots), but the python code thinks there's another folder inside of bots called bots.

Basically, the code is in C:/joe/bots/main.py and the code thinks the file is in C:/joe/bots/bots/passwords.txt while the file is actually in C:/joe/bots/passwords.txt.

This is basically an explanation of the problem and you can just use the code provided by the other guy.

Hope it helps!

Comment: There's no evidence that the path is wrong. The most obvious problem with the code is `while line > 12000:`, which means that no data will ever be read from the file.